# In contentful, how to search in the referenced fields for a particular value of the main content

Tags: reference, contentful

I am somewhat new to references subject within the Contentful… I am looking for a quick help on how to search for a referenced content using POSTMAN. Thanks in advance, here is the scenario.

Main content_type: “person”, which has two fields 1) name “Short Text” and a 2) “videos” field that is defined as reference, which intern has many such references for "video"s for a given person type of content. The referenced content_type “video” has two fields video “title” and “videoURL” for that video.

I need to build a search API to get the value of “videoURL” based on two criteria i.e person.name from the main content type + video.title from the referenced "video" content type  . This is because the same person content can have many “videos” fields pointing to different video contents , however I am interested in a video delivered by a person which has a particular title.

I tried many combinations, but missing the link between the main content person and the child content video. Can you please help me to build this API so that I can use postman API platform , to test using GET request . Thanks a lot I appreciate your help.

I found this from suggestion from contentful website to match

the items[0].fields.videos.sys.id with the "includes.Entry array video.sys.id "

I was able to see physically that we have a matching sysid for video in main content and includes as well, but not able to come up with a suitable GET request to run in the POSTMAN tool.

Any help will be grately appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: I tried using GraphQL but unable to filter further based on a person name and the video title.. below is the query which I ran in GraphQL, it gives me all the videos of all the persons.

Comment: I tried using GraphQL but unable to filter further based on a person name and the video title.. below is the query which I ran in GraphQL, it gives me all the videos of all the persons.  ******************  query getPersonVimeoUrlBasedOnVideoTitle {
  personCollection{
    total
    items{
      name 
      videosCollection{
        items{
        title
        vimeoUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
} ********************** but I need to figure out how to get  or filter the result to get .... a vimeoUrl with a specific title and which belongs to a specific person